# keep press buttons and managment back button

Tags: android, button, back

I have 4 buttons and i want when user clicked on the buttons, button keep pressed. I searched and finally i use this code for keep pressed button. but when i select back button, the program back to before activity but for example when i use back and go to introduce button, the program cannot shows introduce button pressed. The program shows last button press..

How can i solved this problem? Please dont say to me, i use onTouch method and onPressed method because this method cluttered my animation...

```
btnIntroduce.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.introducepress);
btnContact.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contact);
btnMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.more);
btnProduct.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.product);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have written your code to remain in pressed state in onCreate Method, If that is the case Try your code in onResume Method. That will solve the purpose.

Create a new class in your package e.g.

```
public class SaveState {

    public static boolean checkContact, checkIntroduce, checkMore,
            checkProduct;

}
```

Now In your activity ,replace your below code

```
checkContact = true/false;
checkIntroduce = true/false;
checkMore = true/false;
checkProduct = true/false;
```

With

```
    SaveState.checkContact = true/false;
    SaveState.checkIntroduce = true/false;
    SaveState.checkMore = true/false;
    SaveState.checkProduct = true/false;
```

and run your code.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply..Please more explain. What is i add in onResume() method? I write this code in private OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener() method in out of onCreate().

Comment: See what is happening is when you press a button it is working fine but when you come again into this activity after pressing back button the activity got again created so you have to save your pressed button state somewhere and in onResume method you have to again set it pressed.

Comment: You mean i add this code(above code)in onResume()? but how can i understand which button is pressed that i set setBackgroundResource() to press button? If u can please add a part code for more explain..

Comment: I add above code in onResume() and for check, i use 4 boolean variable, but again when i clicked on the back button, the problem not solved !...

Comment: Updated answer, pls chk

Comment: Thanks. I add your code but again i have some problem. When clicked back button, for example first i clicked on the product tab and then i clicked on the conact tab,when i clicked on the back button, fragment about product shows but button of product not changed, contact tab all time is pressed until i clicke on the another tab :( How can i solve this?